# HTML & CSS Table format in approval email template in sharepoint powerautomate

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, approval-process, power-automate

How to prepare a HTML & CSS based table format with all required information in approval email template using power automate?

Answer (score 1):

**Start an approval** action in power automate is currently Markdown supported.

We could use Markdown syntax to add rich formatting and tables in the approval request. Please see this documentation for more details:

[Use Markdown in Power Automate approval requests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/approvals-markdown-support).

However, it doesn’t support fully HTML and CSS. If you really need HTML in approval emails, please submit a request on Flow Ideas Forum so that it might be taken into consideration in the future releases.

[Power Automate Ideas](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Flow-Ideas/idb-p/FlowIdeas).

**Source**: [Send Approval Email Body Formating](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-Approval-Email-Body-Formating/td-p/124577).

Comment: Have you tried this? Is it answers your question?